# What is the difference between API platform and system image in Android?

Tags: android

I am confused between the concept of "API platform" and "System Image" in Android. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Developer Site says that

> The Android **system images** available through the Android SDK Manager *contain code for the Android Linux kernel, the native libraries, the Dalvik VM, and the various Android packages (such as the Android framework and preinstalled applications)*. The emulator provides dynamic binary translation of device machine code to the OS and processor architecture of your development machine.
>
> The **Android platform** provides a *framework API that applications can use to interact with the underlying Android system*. The framework API consists of:
>
> - A core set of packages and classes
> - A set of XML elements and attributes for declaring a manifest file
> - A set of XML elements and attributes for declaring and accessing resources
> - A set of Intents
> - A set of permissions that applications can request, as well as permission enforcements included in the system
>     Each successive version of the Android platform can include updates to the Android application framework API that it delivers.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the web page where you took these excerpts from?

Answer (score 2):

The system image mainly refers to the operating system's code and UI, based on a specific Android distro/version; with or without certain addons; translated for a specific assembly language/architecture.
EX: system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86

The platform is the set of libraries needed to build an app.

Does it matter which platform you use for whatever android system your testing it on?

Well, unless you have a specific combo you're looking for, you want to try to update your apps to the latest platform, and test them on all the different version-addon-arch systems; virtually or physically.

Also, Google APIs are different form platform APIS. They represent the Android version of the Google APIs.
Ex: AdMob replaces AdSense and is an "addon" to the Android platform APIs.

Answer (score 1):

API platform is for developing the application and it is specific to a particular API version. System image is to be installed on the compatible device (or emulator) in order to run the application. It contains the kernel code and driver that are necessary to run the application. Usually platform release includes the system image.

Answer (score 0):

Android system images are just versions of Android that you can run on a computer. So if you wanted to test the very latest stuff you could download an Android O system image and run it on the emulator to see what Android O is like. Or if you wanted to test your app against Android Lollipop, you could download the Lollipop system image and run that.